# Convert one minute candle data to five minute candle with C#

Tags: c#, candlestick-chart, candlesticks

I have open, low, close, high, volume and dateTime of one minute candle, I want to convert that one minute candle to five minute candle

My initial thought about converting one minute candle data to five minute is as below, take 5 candle's of one minute

- 5 minute candle open = first candle's open value
- 5 minute candle high = Max of high values in one minute's 5 candles
- 5 minute candle low = Min of high values in one minute's 5 candles
- 5 minute candle open = last candle's close value
- 5 minute candle volume = sum of all one minute candle's volume

I have created below function to convert the candle

```
 public static List<CandleData> ConvertCandlesTimeFrame1(List<CandleData> candleData, int minutes)
    {
        return candleData
                    .GroupBy(x => new DateTime(x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month, x.Date.Day, x.Date.Hour, x.Date.Minute / minutes * minutes, 0))
                    .Select(g => new CandleData
                    {
                        Date = g.Key,
                        Open = g.First().Open,
                        High = g.Max(x => x.High),
                        Low = g.Min(x => x.Low),
                        Close = g.Last().Close,
                        Volume = g.Sum(x => x.Volume)
                    })
                    .ToList();
    }
```

Above program gives correct output as per my expectations as below

[image]

but I cross checked with broker data, values does not get matches

[image]

Am I missing something or there might be other way of converting one minute candle to five minutes candle?

Comment: Group by Ticks : long FiveMin = 5 * TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;
CandleDate.GroupBy(x => (x.Date.Ticks / FiveMin)  Code does an integer divide and will truncate to 5 minute intervals.

Comment: this still returns same result as before.

Comment: The code will start at a 5 minute interval, not end at a 5 minute interval.  If you want your results subtract one tick from time : CandleDate.GroupBy(x => ((x.Date.Ticks - 1) / FiveMin.  You also want to Order Ascending so the opening time is the first item.

Answer (score -1):

what i understand is the minutes in the reqired data are multiples of 5, so can use the 'Where' in stead of 'GroupBy'

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer? see: [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).